# Error installing package from source in R-3.1.2

Tags: r, installation

I have following error installing RDCOMClient in R-3.1.2 on a Windows machine from source:

`Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/sw/R-3.1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/sw/R-3.1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="RDCOMClient.dll" OBJECTS="COMError.o RUtils.o connect.o converters.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RDCOMClient'`

Same error happens if I do it via install.package or from the command line.
There is no binary available therefore I have to install it from the source.

Here is the package site:
http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/

Can somebody help me please? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you not installing the binary?  In the future, please provide the URL where a package originates, especially for those not available at CRAN .  Did you check all help/instruction files at omegahat?

Comment: There is no binary available therefore I have to install it from the source. I've updated the question with the URL. Thank you!

Comment: There is no binary for 3.1 on Windows. Last version is for 3.0. That's why I'm trying the install from source.

Comment: OK, but did you test to see whether the 3.0 binary will run under 3.1.2?

Comment: I did - and it doesn't: `Error: package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it`. (this is when I installed it from the local .zip). Running install.packages() on remote repo, refuses to do anything, because it doesn't find the 3.1.2 binary. Running install from the source gives the error described in the question.

Comment: Bummer... you may have to contact the package owner and hope he responds.